# Is there GUI for managing gradle packages in IntelliJ IDEA like NuGet in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea, gradle

In Visual Studio there is GUI for choosing which package to install. It is actually very convenient. It is sorted by number of downloads, I can read description, etc

[image]

But I can't find analogous for Gradle in IntelliJ IDEA. The most closely related is "Add library" dialog in ProjectStructure window.

[image]

As you can see it is not very handy. So is there is something in IDEA like in VS?

Comment: Gradle usually gets the dependencies from the same Maven repositories, so you have already found the feature you are looking for. If your project is Gradle based, edit build.gradle instead and Refresh the project, IntelliJ IDEA will update the project dependencies automatically. Usability issues of the Download from Maven dialog can be reported at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I know I can do this, but actually its's a little inconvenient because i should remember package name.